# Installing Porcelain tile over linoleum floor

Tags: flooring, tile, floor

I'm considering installing porcelain tile over an existing linoleum floor.  I've had several contractors come out and they confirmed it would be fine to do and suggested it (I know many posts recommend not doing it, but I am okay with taking that risk).  Without getting into specifics, floor details, etc. I plan on putting hardie backerboard over the linoleum and screwing it into place.  I would like to use a glue/adhesive as well to attach the backerboard to the linoleum since I won't be using thinset between it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I agree with keshlam. All you need to do is screw it down. On a normal tile install you seal the the subfloor and screw down the backer-board so this would be no different, the linoleum is just sandwiched between the sub and the hardy. The only down fall is you cant really seal it.

Comment: The linoleum itself arguably provides a seal...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adhesive would be needed or helpful; what's really holding the backerboard in place are the screws into the subfloor. The linoleum gets buried and becomes mostly irrelevant.

Comment: I think it could help prevent squeaking I've heard in some installations, especially if its a flexible (aka vinyl type adhesive)

Comment: If you feel you need it, lots of construction adhesives should be available in you hardware store, along with "adhesive caulks", in caulking-gun cartridges. I have no opinion on which would be best for this application or if it matters. I'd expect any creaking to come from the subfloor rather than the vinyl or your new layers, though